# JCA or Spring Integration/Camel dilemma

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-integration, jca

Our application needs to accept client requests on a socket (TCP). I have two options

**Use spring integration TCP support**

Pros:
1. We already use spring heavily so there will be less learning curve here. 
2. Simplified end-to-end testing without a container

Concerns:
My concerns are w.r.t handling of concurrent requests and scaling. Can it use managed thread pools? Are there any other things I need to worry about?

**Use JCA TCP Inbound adapter**

Pros:
1. Plays well with a Java EE container as it is the suggested way of implementing this.

Concerns:
1. Hard to find well tested TCP adapter (open source)
2. Requires container

Would appreciate your thoughts on this. Also, any gothcas I should be knowing about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring provides `WorkManagerTaskExecutor` and `TimerManagerTaskScheduler` to use managed thread pools. Any place in Spring Integration that needs a scheduler (e.g. pollers) or task executor can use these abstractions. See the Spring Integration and Spring reference docs for more information.

Comment: Just to add to what Gary's saying... the Spring Integration TCP adapters would address all of your Pros: less learning curve, testing without container, AND plays well with a Java EE container. That last one is where the WorkManager/TimerManager support within Spring enters the picture. In other words, you can have the best of both worlds since the thread pool that the TCP connection factory uses can be one that delegates to container-managed threads.